# Proof that a noetherian integral domain is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic not $2$, and $a\in k$ non-zero. Let $k[x,y]$ be the ring of polynomials in two variables over $k$ and $f:= x^4 + 2(y^2 - a^2)x^2 + (y^4 + 2a^2y^2).$ I have to show that $A:=k[x,y]/(f)$ is integrally closed (I already know that it is an integral domain of dimension $1$).

Since $A$ is Noetherian, I could use the proposition below. I will start from a principal ideal $(\bar g)\subset A$, with $g\in k[x,y]$  and $(\bar g)$ its class of equivalence in $A$. So our principal ideal corresponds to the ideal $(f,g)\subset k[x,y]$; however it seems quite complex to recover its associated primes. Another idea that I had was to prove that all maximal ideals in $A$ are principal, but I don't actually know if it's true, because that would only be a sufficient condition. In fact $A_m$ would be a local Noetherian domain, with dimension $1$ and principle maximal ideal; it would follow that $A_m$ is a discrete valuation ring and so normal. Should I insist in one of these directions or should I find another?

Proposition. A Noetherian domain $A$ is normal if and only if, for every principal ideal $(t)\subset A$ ($t\in A$), the localization $A_p$ is a discrete valuation ring for all the prime ideals $p$ associated to $(t)$. A prime ideal $p$ is said to be associated to an ideal $I$ if, given a minimal primary decomposition $I=q_1\cap\dots \cap q_n$ (so $q_1,\dots , q_n$ are primary ideals), it's true that $p=\sqrt{q_i}$ for some $i\le n$.

Edit: $A$ is normal iff $A_m$ is normal for every maximal ideal $m$. Set $m'=(x,y)$; we observed that $A_{m'}$ is not regular. Since $A_{m'}$ is a local Noetherian of dimension $1$, it is normal iff it is regular, i.e. it isn't normal. So there is a maximal ideal whose localization isn't normal and $A$ can't be normal.

Comment: $a$ is some arbitrary (non-zero I guess?) element of $k$?

Comment: Yes sorry! I corrected

Comment: @Carlos - if $A$ is a regular ring (any localization is a regular local ring) it follows any localization is a DVR hence (AM Thm.9.3) it follows $A$ is integrally closed. Hence if your curve $C:=Spec(A)$ is regular it follows $A$ is integrally closed.

Comment: Thanks. So I know that a criterion to say if $C$ is regular is to verify, for any maximal ideal $m\subset A$, that $\operatorname{rank} J_m=n-\operatorname{dim} A_m=2-1$, where $J_m$ is the vector $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$. However the rank of $J_m$ isn't always $1$, because if $m=(x,y)$ (that corresponds to a maximal ideal in $A$ because $f(0,0)=0$), $J_m=(0,0)$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Carlos - this is a hypersurface and you use partial derivatives to check non-singularity. (Hartshorne, CHI).

Comment: @hm2020 I just edited the question. (The exercise asked *if* $A$ was normal actually)

Comment: Isn't sufficient to prove that there is just a singular point $m$ ? As I said, $A_m$ is regular iff is normal (because it has dimension $1$), so $A_m$ shouldn't be normal for the singular points

Comment: @Carlos: In Atiyah-Macdonald P9.2 and T9.3 it is proved that if $A$ is a noetherian local ring of dimension, one it follows $A$ is integrally closed iff $A$ is regular. Since $\mathfrak{m}:=(0,0)$ is a singularity it follows $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is not integrally closed.

Comment: This is the argument I used in the edit right?